# How can I handle async task cancel when I'm calling it from while condition?

Tags: async-await, cancellationtokensource

I have a loop like this inside a try-catch block:

```
try
{
    while ((receivedBytesCount = await tcpClient.GetStream().ReadAsync(rxBytes, 0, rxBytes.Length, tcpCancellationSource.Token)) != 0)
    {
        // handling rxBytes[]
    }
}
catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Shutting down TCP thread...");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // handle other exceptions
}
```

When I request cancel on `tcpCancellationSource` from somewhere:

```
tcpCancellationSource.Cancel();
```

my application throws OperationCanceledException exception, but not from try-catch block.

**How should I handle that cancellation properly?**

Comment: Are you saying that your `catch (OperationCanceledException oce)` is not getting hit?

Comment: @JohanP Yup. It is not getting hit.

Comment: Are you perhaps using `tcpCancellationSource` in some other async code too that throws the exception?

Comment: @JohanP This might be it, but I changed too many things and now I don't know what helped.